# Linux unzip, extract and remove file

Tags: bash, zip, unzip

With `zip` on Linux we can do:

```
zip -Rm "MyArchive" "*"
```

Where each files are moved inside the archive to save place. Is there a way to do the same for `unzip`?

I have an ugly proposition. Imagine I have `txt` and `csv` files in my `MyArchive.zip`

```
unzip "MyArchive.zip" "*.txt"
zip -d "MyArchive.zip" "*.txt"
unzip "MyArchive.zip" "*.csv"
zip -d "MyArchive.zip" "*.csv"
```

***EDIT1:***

`zip -d` will increase space use while it's running and after end it will free the space. Imagine I have extracted all my `txt` files from `unzip "MyArchive.zip" "*.txt"` at this point I have 80% disk used. While `zip -d "MyArchive.zip" "*.txt"` is running, I hit the 100%

> zip I/O error: No space left on device
>
> zip error: Output file write failure (write error on zip file)

Since `zip -d` ended, space is freed but none of my `txt` files are removed from the archive, so I'm back at 80% disk used. To recap, `zip -d` is extremely slow ,eats disk space and doesn't remove anything if it fails.

***EDIT2:***

Here is what I tried
I read inside my zip archive, get the first file inside the archive. I `unzip` this particular file, then remove it from the original archive. And repeat until archive is empty.

```
while :
do
    file="$(sed -n "1p" <<< "$(unzip -Z1 $MyArchive)")"
    if [ "$file" ];then
        unzip "$MyArchive" "$file"
        zip -d "$MyArchive" "$file"
    else
        break
    fi 
done
```

None of this is working the way I thought. Why? Because `zip -d` is creating a temporary file to replace the original zip file. Slow and useless.

Comment: It's impossible what you want.

Comment: Removing a file from a zip archive involves rewriting the *entire* file.

Comment: Yup, that's what I noticed... So it's physically impossible to do what I want.